# Google Apps - Can I configure a wildcard MX record and and catch all emai address for a domain

Tags: email-server, g-suite, mx-record

I am using Google Apps Premier Edition.

I want to create a disposable email address service and I want to catch all emails for a domain. This means that I should be able to catch all mails sent to an arbitrary userid and/or arbitrary domain and store them into a single Google Apps account.

For example, in a single account I want to get all mails sent to:

1) abc@mydomain.com
2) abc@xyz.mydomain.com

without requiring to do any extra configuration in Google Apps for abc or xyz. My app will download mails from this account and process accordingly.

I have figured out that I could do (1) by specifying a catch all email address.

Is the combination of both (1) and (2) possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit unsure... Do you mean that the "xyz" subdomain will be disposable? I will assume so.

As you say, 1) is easy and support is built in, but 2) requires you to register the subdomain as a separate google apps account, so if you mean for that to be disposable then you are out of luck. Once you have registered the subdomain the it will be a separate account, and you can set up a catch all for that too.

Subdomains with email accounts, such as abc@xyz.mydomain.com also requires the appropriate MX (and SPF) records in DNS for that subdomain, what its parent has is irrelevant.

In short, no. I don't think what you want to do is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do abc-xyx@mydomain.com. This is sometimes referred to as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question #1: It sounds like you want to set up MX records for a wildcard DNS domain (Something like *.example.com).

Does this [example from Wikipedia help you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record#Definitions_of_DNS_wildcards)?

```
*.example.com.   3600 IN  MX 10 host1.example.com.
```

This would set the MX record for xyz.example.com and abc.example.com.

Step 2 would be to convince Google Apps to accept email for any domain like *.example.com. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Google Apps for the domain example.com will accept all mail for *.example.com and foo@x.example.com and foo@y.example.com map to the same account so there is nothing you need to do on the google side. The wildcard MX is all that is needed.

Comment: embobo, seems like your suggestion is not working.. I've added a wildcard MX record, sent an email to "info@test.mydomain.com" but Google responded with "550 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist".